# Sed select value of parameter

Tags: sed

I need to extract value using `sed` command;
I have a file, that contains something like this:

```
field="value"
```

The result needs to be: `value`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page.  In general, we prefer to help people who've made an honest attempt to solve their problem, and who demonstrate that by showing their best attempt.  Your question is imprecise.  Does the file you're extracting from have one line or many lines? Are all the lines of the form `field="value"`? Do you need to find the value for a specific field, or all the values for all fields? What if there are two lines with the same field name — one or two outputs? All are doable; they're fairly straight-forward applications of regular expressions.

Comment: Not sed but you may try this `perl -lne 'print $1 if(/field=\"([^\"]*)\"/)'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                                    
sed -n 's/field="\(.*\)"/\1/p'
```

This looks for lines that have field=

If it finds them, it removes everything except the value, and prints the value.
Otherwise, it prints nothing.

Comment: since he has a file suggest that he cat the file and pipe it to sed to improve the answer... cheers +1

Comment: Yup. Save the file above as "prog" and use it like
./prog <file

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide an `awk` alternative, since `awk` is often the better choice when it comes to *field*-based processing.

Your exact requirements are unclear, but here I'm making the following assumptions:

- field names are unique
- there are no spaces around the `=` and all values are `"`-enclosed

The following allows you to pass in a field name via the `-v fname=...` option and returns that field's value unquoted; sample input is provided via a here-document.

```bsh
awk -F\" -v fname='field' '$1 == (fname "=") { print $2; exit }' <<'EOF'
key="largo"
field="value"
id="fake"
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use awk to look for "field", split the fields up using '=', and then deleting the extra quotes using tr

```
awk -F= '/field/ {print $2}' <file | tr -d '"'
```